# Launcher Icons Fuzzy

Tags: 12.10, launcher, icons

I have had blurry icons in my launcher ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10. I have included a print screen.

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Launcher Icon Size set to an odd number? Try setting it to an even one; it worked for me. [It's a confirmed bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1074607%)

Comment: That was the issue. How weird!